# Is there a way to update parallels without using automatic updates?

Tags: upgrade, software-update, parallels-desktop

I need to be able to download updates to Parallels on one machine and then distribute the update to multiple, other machines, on a separate network.

Is there a way to do this? I've tried to both search [kb.parallels.com](http://kb.parallels.com/), as well as Google this.  I can't find anything explicitly stating whether this is or isn't possible.

If I can download updates from an external source for manual installation, where do I go to get these updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to download updated version on one computer and use it on other machines, download and install the latest Parallels Desktop 7 update:

1. Download the update from http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/download/dr/
2. Run the downloaded file and re-install Parallels Desktop. Note: only Parallels Desktop application will be reinstalled, no Virtual Machines will be affected.

Comment: The link you've provided actually redirects you to download a DMG named `ParallelsDesktop-7.0.15106.786747.dmg`.  Does this link always provide the most up-to-date version of Parallels.  Also, will it update my current version of Parallels, which is at 7.0.15104 or is it a full re-install?  Sorry for the extra questions, I just want to know what I'm getting into before I execute the downloaded file.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello Again, It will always download the most upto date version. And it wont do a fresh install. Just download and run it it will automatically update the previous version to the new version.

Comment: The newer the better :-) Technically it's a re-install but you will lose neither your configurations nor your VMs. I've done this many times already without problems.

Comment: I can see that you have 15104 and it will update to 15106 :) .